# Upload from Cloud9 (c9) IDE to FTP server

Tags: ftp, ide, cloud9-ide

I'm trying to find a simple way to upload a project, or even just a single file, from the Cloud9 (c9.io) IDE to an existing live FTP server. I see that I can now connect (via a Beta feature) to an FTP or SFTP server from c9, but I can't seem to upload edited files from the IDE via FTP.

Maybe I'm missing something, but I was hoping to deploy directly from c9.

Thank you in advance for any assistance you're able to offer!

Comment: https://c9.io/support

Comment: Hi ceejayoz, I did check their documentation, but there's nothing there that addresses the question that I could find. The FTP mount is a new beta feature, and I was thinking that there may be some undocumented features that aren't readily known.

Comment: "If you can't find an answer to your question, get in touch with Cloud9 Support via Twitter, or by filing a bug report."

Comment: I think best options are sshfs or git-ftp. For vue apps, ftp-deploy.

Answer (score 1):

From documentation:

> Cloud9 IDE allows you to easily add files to your curent workspace at any time. You can drag and drop files from your computer directly into the Project Files pane, and the IDE will add them to your project. Google Chrome users can also drag entire folders into the IDE.

[click for more information](https://docs.c9.io/uploading_downloading.html)